# how 's to scan html5 qrcode for decode chinese

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qr-code

i try to html5 javascript to decode qrcode by mobile camera
now i get [1](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) but why didn't it to decode chinese ?
how's to do , where to do to make know chinese?

```
var parser = new BitMatrixParser(bits);
var version = parser.readVersion();
var ecLevel = parser.readFormatInformation().ErrorCorrectionLevel;

// Read codewords
var codewords = parser.readCodewords();

// Separate into data blocks
var dataBlocks = DataBlock.getDataBlocks(codewords, version, ecLevel);

// Count total number of data bytes
var totalBytes = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < dataBlocks.Length; i++)
{
    totalBytes += dataBlocks[i].NumDataCodewords;
}
var resultBytes = new Array(totalBytes);
var resultOffset = 0;

// Error-correct and copy data blocks together into a stream of bytes
for (var j = 0; j < dataBlocks.length; j++)
{
    var dataBlock = dataBlocks[j];
    var codewordBytes = dataBlock.Codewords;
    var numDataCodewords = dataBlock.NumDataCodewords;
    Decoder.correctErrors(codewordBytes, numDataCodewords);
    for (var i = 0; i < numDataCodewords; i++)
    {
        resultBytes[resultOffset++] = codewordBytes[i];
    }
}

// Decode the contents of that stream of bytes
var reader = new QRCodeDataBlockReader(resultBytes, version.VersionNumber, ecLevel.Bits);
return reader;
//return DecodedBitStreamParser.decode(resultBytes, version, ecLevel);
```